# serializing result of a queryset with json raises error:

Tags: python, django, json, serialization

I was trying to serialize a Python list but got errors that it's not serializable.  Is there a limitation on serializing a list of Long integers?

```
>>> ids=p.values_list('id',flat=True)
>>> ids
[335L, 468L, 481L, 542L, 559L, 567L, 609L]
>>> import simplejson as json
>>> str=json.dumps(ids)

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\simplejson\simplejson\__ini
t__.py", line 265, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\simplejson\simplejson\encod
er.py", line 216, in encode
    chunks = list(chunks)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\simplejson\simplejson\encod
er.py", line 495, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\simplejson\simplejson\encod
er.py", line 190, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: [335L, 468L, 481L, 542L, 559L, 567L, 609L] is not JSON serializable
>>>
```

Comment: it works for me either with simplejson and json. btw, it is a bad idea to assign to `str`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

"I am trying to serialize a Python list..."
This is actually not quite the full story.
You are trying to serialize a `ValuesListQuerySet`.

```
>>> type(ids)
<class 'django.db.models.query.ValuesListQuerySet'>
```

You can either
 1. convert to a Python list as mentioned in the other great answers, or
 2. serialize just the IDs.

Django has a built-in way to serialize a `QuerySet`.
And you only want the IDs so you may use the [`fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#subset-of-fields) kwarg.

```
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize('json', YourEntity.objects.all(), fields=('id',))
```

Comment: wouldn't that mean, catching all data first and then just using the id field? Sounds little performant

Answer (score 4):

### EDIT after reading the other answers

The original answer I gave (here below unabridged) was correct in diagnosing what the problem is (**the argument passed to the json function is not a list**). I am leaving it as it explains the debugging procedure (maybe of some use for other similar situations), but the new answers of both @Jacinda and @Adam are more "to the point". In particular, the latter contains instructions on how to use a native django functionality to overcome the problem.

### Original answer

Not 100% sure because I can't replicate the problem on my system, but from the look of it, it seems to me that it's a problem in the type/encoding of the data.

I would start by testing again your code by manually assign `ids` with:

```
ids = [335L, 468L, 481L, 542L, 559L, 567L, 609L]
```

(on my system your code works in this case). If it works for you too, then investigate what kind of object is `ids` when assigned via `p.values_list('id',flat=True)` [you can do that with `type(ids)`]. It might be that `ids` is an object whose representation is the same as a list, but that it's not a list.

In this case, you could try typecasting: `ids = list(p.values_list('id',flat=True))` before passing it to the json function but there is no guarantee that it will work (it depends if the returned value of `p.values_list` is iterable or not.

HTH in at least tracking down the issue!

Comment: This is a helpful answer. I hope that you do not delete it. And for the record, your suggestion works (converting the `ValuesListQuerySet` to a Python list).

Comment: @afshin - without seeing the code it's difficult to make a diagnosis, maybe you could put in some pastebin and put the link in the comments... or make another question about your problem here on SO. The only thing coming to my mind: are you sure you are using the built-in function `list` and not some `list` method of a class, that would expect `self` as first argument?

Comment: Here is the code - equivalent to this code works fine on the shell:           s = StoryCat.objects.filter(category=c)
   ids=s.values_list('id',flat=True)
   ids=list(ids)
   str= json.dumps( ids )
   return HttpResponse(ids)

Comment: @afshin - Odd. From your non-working code try this: `print type(list)` the result should be: `<type 'type'>`. And then you can try `print help(list)` and you should see the signature `list(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items`. If this is not the case: somewhere in your code the `list` has been redefined to something else (this is what I think it happened). If this is not the case: I have no idea, sorry! (Please when you find out, post a new comment... I'm curious to know what's going on...).

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same error and after a lot of confusion, finally the solution that worked for me is as follows in a single answer for the question asked by @afshin:

```
ids = p.values_list('id',flat=True)
ids_list = list(ids)
import json
json.dumps(ids_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `values_list()`, which is a django function (you probably should clarify this in your question) does not return a list.

```
>>> x = UserProfile.objects.values_list('employee_id', flat=True)
>>> type(x)
>>> <class 'django.db.models.query.ValuesListQuerySet'>
```

simplejson.dumps doesn't know how to serialize this object.  So like @mac suggested, you need to typecast this return value to a list.